# Howto manually call validations on AR object with bang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I would have expected rails to have something like a `validate!` method on AR objects, however I can't find anything like it.

I want to be able to call validations on an object and raising whatever errors there might be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Strict validations when you want raise exceptions when an object is invalid.
But you need to specify the strict parameter on each validation. You can also pass custom exceptions to raise to the strict parameter. This is the only way i'm aware of for your solution.

Sample:
`validates :name, presence: { strict: true }`

You still need to validate with `object.valid?`

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html
Chapter 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_object.valid?
```

This runs the validations and adds errors for any that fail, which you can see with .errors

Generally you wouldn't raise an exception if an object fails validation:  exceptions should be saved for unexpected problems, not anticipated problems like validation failure.

Comment: Well, however I'm interested in raising them. I use exceptions to control a flow in my application. So how would you then raise those errors like it's done if calling `.save!`

Comment: `raise "Validation failed" unless my_object.valid?`

I still think you shouldn't do this, but hey.